# Admin bar default color scheme for nonregistered/nonlogged users

Tags: css, admin-bar, admin-css

I have disabled the registered users to select the admin color scheme as I want all of them to use the 'Coffee' scheme. I have also made the 'Coffee' color scheme the default one for registered users.

However, WordPress still shows the default (black) admin bar for nonregistered/nonlogged users of the website.

Do you know how I can force it show the admin bar in the 'Coffee' color scheme even in those cases?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has now been solved using the following code in functions.php

```
function your_custom_function_name()

{

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . admin_url('css/colors/coffee/colors.css') . '" type="text/css">';

}

add_action('admin_print_styles', 'your_custom_function_name');

add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'your_custom_function_name');
```

Keep in mind the code above works for the 'Coffee' color scheme. If you want to use any of the other color scheme, you need to change the admin_url(parameter) to reference the correct directory.

And if you haven't yet set the desired color scheme as default for all users, you can use this piece of code (again, in functions.php)

```
function your_other_custom_function_name($user_id) {

    $args = array(

    'ID' => $user_id,

    'admin_color' => 'coffee'

    );

    wp_update_user( $args );

    add_action('user_register', 'your_other_custom_function_name');

}
```

Once again, you need to change the 'admin_color' => 'parameter' to match your desired color scheme

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Use the following code in your functions.php or your site specific
   plugin:

   ```
   function set_default_admin_color($user_id) {
       $args = array(
           'ID' => $user_id,
           'admin_color' => 'coffee'
       );
       wp_update_user( $args );
   }
   add_action('user_register', 'set_default_admin_color');
   ```
2. Now, add these lines to force "Coffee" color scheme to be displayed
   in the admin bar:

   ```
   if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') )
   remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
   ```

Comment: That only solves it for registered/logged users. The bar remains with the default black for unregistered/unlogged users.